# what does a ampersand before double colon mean in c++?

Tags: c++

I found this usage in the following code generated by google's protobuf.

```
inline void Datum::set_data(const void* value, size_t size) {
  set_has_data();
  //over here.
  if (data_ == &::google::protobuf::internal::kEmptyString) {
     data_ = new ::std::string;
  }
 data_->assign(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(value), size);
}
```

Thank you:-)!

Comment: It's an address of `kEmptyString`.

Comment: [`::` has highest precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), hence it'll be evaluated before `&`

Comment: Using a `::` prefix for things that are not in the global namespace is unnecessary. Anyone who defines a `my_lib::std::string` will be condemned to burn in purgatory forever. Therefore using `std::string` is enough. Avoid the clutter!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's two totally unrelated things, perhaps better thought of as

```
&(::google::protobuf::internal::kEmptyString)
```

`&` just means the address-of operator, exactly the same as if you'd done:

```
int xyzzy = 7;
int *pointer_to_xyzzy = &xyzzy;
```

The `::`, on the other hand, is the global namespace specifier, to ensure you don't start looking in your *current* namespace.

For example, the following program:

```
#include <iostream>

int x = 7;
namespace xyzzy {
    int x = 42;
    int getxa() { return ::x; }
    int getxb() { return x; }
}

int main() {
    std::cout << xyzzy::getxa() << '\n';
    std::cout << xyzzy::getxb() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

outputs `7` followed by `42` since the `getxa()` function uses the global namespace specifier rather than the `xyzzy` one.